# How to plot a increasing learning curve of polynomial regression

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, scikit-learn, linear-regression, non-linear-regression

I am trying to plot the fitted curve after using polynomial feature with the following code, but it is not coming out right. How do I plot only single fitted curve?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

m = 100
X = 6 * np.random.rand(m,1) - 3
Y = 0.5 * X**2 + X + 2 + np.random.randn(m,1)

from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

poly_features = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2,include_bias=False)
X_poly = poly_features.fit_transform(X)

lin = LinearRegression()

lin.fit(X_poly,Y)
Y_pred = lin.predict(X_poly)

plt.scatter(X, Y)
plt.plot(X_poly,Y_pred,color='red')
plt.show()
```

[image: Click to see the matplotlib plot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)
m = 100
X = 6 * np.random.rand(m) - 3
Y = 0.5 * X**2 + X + 2 + np.random.randn(m)

from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

poly_features = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2,include_bias=False)
X_poly = poly_features.fit_transform(X.reshape(-1,1))

lin = LinearRegression()

lin.fit(X_poly,Y)
Y_pred = lin.predict(X_poly)

idx = X.argsort()

plt.scatter(X, Y)
plt.plot(X[idx],Y_pred[idx],color='red')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It worked like a magic, but can you please tell me what was I doing wrong and how did it solved that.

Comment: You should have paid attention to the order of arguments you supplied to `plt.plot`. I ordered it, increasing, thus the line goes smoothly from left to right. You did not. Thus your line went randomly from point to point in your interval. Plus, I slightly changed the dimensions of your input array, from (m,1) to (m,). This is not crucial, but the code is cleaner. If you wish, I can re-edit with your dimensions.